# Equation of Linear Operators

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, and let $S$ and $T$ be linear operators on $V$.

(a) Prove that, if $S$ is invertible, then $T$ and $STS^{-1}$ have the same set of eigenvalues.

(b) Prove that, if $ST-TS = S$, then $S$ is not invertible. Hint: Consider the eigenvalue of $T$ with the largest real part.

Would appreciate a proof check for (a) and some help for (b).

(a) Since $V$ is a complex vector space, $T$ has at least 1 eigenvalue, say $\lambda$. Let $u$ be an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda$. Now, consider the image of $Su$ under $(STS^{-1})$. We have,

\begin{align*}
STS^{-1}(Su) = STu = S\lambda u = \lambda Su,
\end{align*}
so $Su$ is an eigenvector of $STS^{-1}$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

(b) I'm not quite sure how the hint comes into play here. My first idea was to assume to get a contradiction that $S$ was invertible. Then $S^{-1}$ exists. By the same reason in (a), $T$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda$ and corresponding eigenvector $u$. Now consider the image $S^{-1}u$ under $ST-TS$. We have,

\begin{align*}
(ST-TS)S^{-1}u = STS^{-1}
u-Tu = (STS^{-1}-\lambda I)u\end{align*}.

However, this is also equal to $Su$, which cannot be 0 (again by the same reason in (a)) but $(STS^{-1}-\lambda I)$ must be 0 since $T$ and $STS^{-1}$ share eigenvalues, a contradiction.

This seems like it is correct to me, but my solution doesn't use the hint for part (b). Am I missing something?

**Update:**
One can prove an even stronger version of (a), that being that $T$ and $STS^{-1}$ has the same characteristic polynomial as $T$ hence the same multiset of eigenvalues.

Proof: Starting with the characteristic polynomial of $STS^{-1}$, we see,
\begin{align*}
\det(STS^{-1}-\lambda I) = \det(S(T-\lambda I)S^{-1}) = \det(S)\det(T-\lambda I)\det(S^{-1})= \det(T-\lambda I),
\end{align*}
as desired.

Comment: $(STS^{-1}-\lambda I)u$ need not be $0$. $\lambda$ is an eigen value of $STS^{-1}$ but $u$ need not be an eigen vector corresponding to this  eigen value.

Comment: Ah good catch. So there is definitely something missing here...

Comment: For the first part, you also need to show that all of the eigenvalues of $STS^{-1}$ are also eigenvalues of $T$.

Comment: i think i've already done since $\lambda$ was arbitrary.

Comment: You have shown that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $STS^{-1}$. You still need to show that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $STS^{-1}$, then $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. This shows that the two sets of eigenvalues are equal.

Comment: Yes you're right. How does this work:

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $STS^{-1}$ with corresponding eigenvector $u$ then $STS^{-1}u = \lambda u$. Premultiplying both sides by $S^{-1}$ we get $TS^{-1}u = S^{-1}\lambda u = \lambda S^{-1}u$. Since $S^{-1}$ is invertible, $S^{-1}u$ is nonzero, so $S^{-1}u$ is a eigenvector of $STS^{-1}$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: the standard finish to (b) would be to write $(ST-TS)S^{-1} =I$ as you did but then take the trace to get a contradiction.  You can actually strengthen (b) quite a bit to show $S$ must be nilpotent (a part of Jacobson's Lemma).  Your part (a) is a bit pecuiliar -- it only asks about sets of eigenvalues but typically a question like this would ask about having the same multi-sets of eigenvalues (i.e. algebraic multiplicities match) or equivalently that they have the same characteristic polynomials.

Comment: @user8675309 oh thanks this helps a lot. I think this is the idea.

Let $n$ denote the dimension of $V$ and assume to get a contradiction that $S$ is invertible, then $(ST - TS)S^{-1} = I$ which implies $STS^{-1} - T = I$. Taking the trace of both sides we get tr$(STS^{-1})-tr(T) = tr(I)$ but  tr$(STS^{-1})$ = tr$(T)$ from part (a), so $0 = n$ a contradiction. 

Again, I don't see how this uses the "eigenvalue with the largest real component" though...

Comment: you can justify $\text{trace}\big(STS^{-1}\big)=\text{trace}\big(T\big)$ with cyclic property of trace or because they have the same characteristic polynomials (i.e. all eigenvalues $\in \mathbb C$, with *algebraic multiplicity* agree) **but** once again you did not show this or attempt to show this in part (a) -- what you've done, at best, shows the eigenvalues have the same *geometric multiplicities* so more work is needed on part (a) if you want it to justify (b)

Comment: @user8675309 Okay I am trying to show that they have the same algebraic multiplicity, but I'm not sure exactly how. I am aware that for any polynomial $f(x)$ if we evaluate $f(STS^{-1}) = Sf(T)S^{-1}$, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Also still unsure how the largest real component of an eigenvalue could come into play here.

Comment: I leave (a) with you -- directly working with determinants and characteristic polynomials is easiest.  Or argue the two matrices are similar to the same upper triangular matrix.  Either way this should force you to think through what algebraic multiplicities are.  For (b) let $\lambda' =a' + b'\cdot i$ have the maximal real part $a'$ and suppose $S$ invertible: $ST-TS = S\implies STS^{-1}=T+I$ so LHS has max real part of $a'$ and the RHS has maximal real part $a'+1$, a contradiction.

Comment: What do you mean by "LHS has max real part of $a'$"? I also still don't understand why it is necessary to consider this specific eigenvalue. Wouldn't any eigenvalue suffice to show the same thing?

Comment: @Important_man74 you need to tag me with comments.  OP always gets notified, not so for everyone else...  Left Hand Side has eigenvalue with max real part $a'$ because $S T S^{-1}$ has same characteristic polynomial (eigenvalue multiset) as $T$-- this follows from (a) which you still have not done.  Keep in mind I also gave you a complete proof of (b) using the trace.  I think you need to spend time proving (a), and do so several different ways and type up your proofs on this site.  Then these different solutions to (b) may make sense to you.

Comment: @user8675309 So, the characteristic polynomial of $STS^{-1}$ is \begin{align*}\det(STS^{-1}-\lambda I) &= \det(S(T-\lambda I) S^{-1}\\
&= \det(S)\det(T-\lambda I) \det S^{-1}\\
&= \det(T-\lambda I),
\end{align*}
So $T$ and $STS^{-1}$ have the same characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Yes.  Aside from some parenthesis nits that's the typical argument for (a)-- best to put it in the OP with an 'update' note.  So re-consider $STS^{-1}=T+I $$\implies \det(T-\lambda I)=\det(STS^{-1}-\lambda I)=\det(T+I-\lambda I)=\det(T+(1-\lambda) I)$.  My approach is to look at the trace. Your book's hint is if $\lambda'$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ such that $a'=Re(\lambda')$ is the max real part amongst all eigenvalues, then the Left Hand Side (LHS) is $\neq 0$ for any $\lambda\mapsto z$ when $Re(z)\gt a'$ by definition, but the RHS $=0$ at $\lambda\mapsto\lambda' +1$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: @user8675309 okay great this has helped a lot. I appreciate it!